# Open and Close Cursors Inside or Outside a Transaction and How to Close a Cursor if a Transaction Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, transactions, database-cursor

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that uses a cursor for reading and a transaction inside a `TRY CATCH` block.  Basically, my questions are as follows:

1. Should I declare my cursor inside the `TRY CATCH` block?  If yes, should I declare the cursor before or after the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement?
2. Should I open the cursor before or after the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement?
3. Should I close and deallocate the cursor before or after the `COMMIT TRANSACTION` statement?
4. Should I close and deallocate the cursor before or after the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` statement if something fails?

**Sample T-SQL Code:**

```
DECLARE @ColumnID AS INT;
DECLARE @ColumnName AS VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @ColumnValue AS FLOAT;

-- Should I declare my cursor inside the TRY CATCH block?
-- If yes, should I declare the cursor before or after the BEGIN TRANSACTION statement?

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT
        a.ColumnID,
        a.ColumnName,
        a.ColumnValue

    FROM
        MyTable a;

BEGIN TRY

    -- Should I open the cursor before or after the BEGIN TRANSACTION statement?

    BEGIN TRANSACTION myTransaction;

    OPEN myCursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @ColumnID, @ColumnName, @ColumnValue;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

        IF (@ColumnName IS NULL) BEGIN

            UPDATE
                MyTable

            SET
                @ColumnValue = NULL

            WHERE
                ColumnID = @ColumnID;

        END;

        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @ColumnID, @ColumnName, @ColumnValue;

    END;

    -- Should I close and deallocate the cursor before or after the COMMIT TRANSACTION statement?

    CLOSE myCursor;
    DEALLOCATE myCursor;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION myTransaction;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    -- Should I close and deallocate the cursor before or after the ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement:

    IF CURSOR_STATUS('local', 'myCursor') = 1 BEGIN

        CLOSE myCursor;
        DEALLOCATE myCursor;

    END;

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION myTransaction;

END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would declare and open the cursor before the `BEGIN TRY` and then close and deallocate it after the `END CATCH` to minimize the amount of time you're spending in the transaction. This also means you don't need to write the close/deallocate statements twice.

My second choice would be to declare and open the cursor inside the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and then close and deallocate before the `ROLLBACK`. I'm sure others will prefer this style.

These ways the cursor is either entirely outside the try/catch and transaction or entirely contained within them. Doing it otherwise feels like crossing scopes to me, but would certainly still work. I think this question is mainly an issue of style