# Close and Deallocate Cursor and Try-Catch in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exception

I'm writing a stored procedure in TSQL which uses a transaction and a cursor. I'm wondering if I should place `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` within a TRY block - can these statements throw?

My code is structured like this:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT -- Select statement left out for brevity's sake

BEGIN TRY
    OPEN myCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor -- INTO statement left out for brevity's sake

    WHILE @@FETCHSTATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Here I process each item in the cursor
        -- and then fetch the items for the next loop run
        FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
    END;

    CLOSE myCursor;
    DEALLOCATE myCursor;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    CLOSE myCursor;
    DEALLOCATE myCursor;
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;

END CATCH
```

I have the following specific questions:

- Can `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` throw an exception in this specific case? If yes, this would mean that I would need another TRY-CATCH block to safely close the cursor, otherwise, the actual error that occurred in the TRY block could be lost. I couldn't find any info on this [in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/close-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28485075/1560623) suggests it wouldn't do that.
- Should I remove the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` statement in the CATCH block? Is the transaction automatically rolled-back when an exception is thrown?
- Is there any way to avoid the duplicate `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` statements in this piece of code?

**Update after Martin Smith's comment:**

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743428/1560623), I could declare a cursor variable which is automatically closed and deallocated when the variable goes out of scope. I'm not a 100% sure if this is actually happening: according to the [DEALLOCATE docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/deallocate-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017), `DEALLOCATE` is called, but in the [CLOSE docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/close-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), nothing is stated regarding automatic behavior.

Additional questions:

- **Does using a variable really automatically close and deallocate the cursor?** I have my doubts about that as CLOSE is not called automatically according to the docs. Unless something like reference counting is done internally.add
- **If it really works, why call CLOSE at all on a local cursor that is only referenced once?**

Comment: I'd just d[eclare the cursor as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737586/tsql-cursor-how-to-check-if-already-declared-and-thus-deallocate/8743428#8743428) then it is automatically closed and deallocated when goes out of scope.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the info. Can you point to some official documentation? I want to properly close the cursor (object), and the answer as well as [this doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/deallocate-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017) only talks about the variable (stack-based construct?). My background is C# and I don't know if it applies in TSQL as well, but a variable is always on the stack and deallocated automatically when a function (stored procedure in this case) ends? Or is there some reference counting going on internally?

Comment: I've update my question regarding variables and cursors.

Comment: `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` serve different purposes. `CLOSE` leaves the cursor available for reopening later; `DEALLOCATE` decreases the reference count and causes the cursor to be freed when the last reference is gone. This freeing is not the same as closing the cursor -- if a cursor is fully deallocated but not closed, the locks the cursor held (if any) remain in place until the end of the transaction, per the docs. In your situation this does not really matter because the cursor lives and dies with the transaction anyway -- even if it was not properly closed, it would still go away on error.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your comment. According to what you said, the simplest thing I should do is actually nothing? Because when I commit the transaction or roll it back, the local cursor is closed and deallocated automatically?

Comment: The simplest thing you *could* do is nothing, but closing and deallocating anyway doesn't seem wrong to me. Declaring a cursor is not transactional; opening it is. What would probably improve this code in any case is `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and changing the `ROLLBACK` to `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK`, to cover the case where SQL Server has already implicitly rolled back the transaction and your `ROLLBACK` would cause an error. [See also](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern). This is not directly related to the use of cursors, of course.

Comment: Furthermore, because you're using a `STATIC` cursor the results of your `SELECT` are effectively materialized in a temp table first, so the cursor should not be keeping any open locks on the base table(s) anyway, making it even less interesting what happens with closing/deallocating it, as the temp table will surely not survive the transaction on rollback, much less the batch. I'd do the `CLOSE` / `DEALLOCATE` dance for neatness only. (Whether they can throw themselves, if used on a valid open cursor, is something I think only God knows. They shouldn't, but...)

Comment: First thing's first: **are you sure you actually need a cursor?** Can't the code be executed with a set based approach instead?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm not a TSQL expert, but I think: yes, I do. In each loop run, I insert a row to a table and that entry needs a dynamically calculated `HierarchyId`. I use `HierarchyId.GetDescendant(leftChild, rightChild)` for that where left child is the hierarchy ID of the entry inserted in the previous loop run. There is possibly a way to calculate that in a set-based fashion (maybe with a CTE?), but I'm not quite sure about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` throw an exception in this specific case?

I don't see how either one could throw an error in any case. They simply release the resources. It would certainly be possible that down-stream operations that are expecting the cursor to exist can error if the cursor has been closed or deallocated (depending on what was expected)

> Should I remove the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` statement in the `CATCH` block? Is the transaction automatically rolled-back when an exception is thrown?

No, don't remove the `ROLLBACK`. You will need that no matter what, although that is something that is usually wrapped in a test for `IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)`.

If `XACT_ABORT` is `OFF` (the default) then the transaction could likely still be open so you will need to do the `ROLLBACK`. If `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`, then the transaction is already rolled-back, BUT the transaction is also in an uncommittable state at which point the only thing you can do is issue a `ROLLBACK`. So, either way, you need the `ROLLBACK`.

> Is there any way to avoid the duplicate `CLOSE` and `DEALLOCATE` statements in this piece of code?

No, not really. BUT, you *could* get away with only having the `DEALLOCATE` statement as it will close the cursor first. (see example below)

> Does using a variable really automatically close and deallocate the cursor?

Not sure about the variable, but I do know that it isn't necessary. All you need is for the cursor to be `LOCAL` (which you are already doing) and it will automatically deallocate at the end of the batch. (see example below)

> If it really works, why call `CLOSE` at all on a local cursor that is only referenced once?

Probably because most people aren't aware that local cursors are automatically deallocated at the end of the batch (I didn't until I did the test so that I could answer this question), *and* the default scope for cursors (unless changed at the DB level and I doubt most people mess with that setting, not knowing how it will impact built-in stored procedures) is `GLOBAL`, so they did need to be deallocate them.

The following tests show the difference between `LOCAL` and `GLOBAL` (default on most systems) cursors, and that `DEALLOCATE` by itself is just fine (assuming you don't need to re-run the cursor query again):

```sql
DECLARE myLocalCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT TOP (10) [object_id] FROM sys.objects;

SELECT 'DECLARE (local)' AS [Step], @@CURSOR_ROWS AS [Rows], *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID);
-- 1 row
GO

SELECT 'NEXT BATCH (local)' AS [Step], @@CURSOR_ROWS AS [Rows], *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID);
-- no rows

DECLARE myGlobalCursor CURSOR GLOBAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT TOP (10) [object_id] FROM sys.objects;

SELECT 'DECLARE (global)' AS [Step], @@CURSOR_ROWS AS [Rows], *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID);
-- 1 row
GO

SELECT 'NEXT BATCH (global)' AS [Step], @@CURSOR_ROWS AS [Rows], *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID);
-- 1 row (same cursor_id as previous SELECT)

DEALLOCATE myGlobalCursor;

SELECT 'DEALLOCATE (global)' AS [Step], @@CURSOR_ROWS AS [Rows], *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID);
-- no rows
GO
```

And:

```sql
-- open cursor then deallocate (do not close first):
DECLARE CursorToDeallocate CURSOR GLOBAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT TOP (10) [object_id] FROM sys.objects;

SELECT 'DECLARE (global2)' AS [Step], @@CURSOR_ROWS AS [Rows], *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID);
-- 1 row

OPEN CursorToDeallocate;
SELECT 'OPEN (global2)' AS [Step], @@CURSOR_ROWS AS [Rows], *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID);
-- 1 row

DEALLOCATE CursorToDeallocate;

SELECT 'DEALLOCATE (global2)' AS [Step], @@CURSOR_ROWS AS [Rows], *
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cursors(@@SPID);
-- no rows
GO
```

From your [documentation issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2987):

> Do you have to call `CLOSE` and then `DEALLOCATE`? Is there an automatic mechanism that does this?

Generally speaking, yes, you `CLOSE` first which keeps the cursor allocated, and then you can `DEALLOCATE`. If you call `DEALLOCATE` first, then the cursor is automatically closed. By merely closing a cursor, it is still defined and can be re-run simply by executing `OPEN` on it again (no need to re-declare it).

Regarding automatically `CLOSE` or `DEALLOCATE`:

1. A `LOCAL` cursor is automatically closed and deallocated when the batch ends
2. Please see [SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-cursor-close-on-commit-transact-sql)

> Can you provide information what `DEALLOCATE` actually does internally?

As far as I know, `DEALLOCATE` just de-lists the cursor definition from `sys.dm_exec_cursors` (well, wherever that data is stored). And, of course, closes the cursor if it's not already closed (at least in the sense that no cursor means that there is no cursor to be either open or closed, or maintain any locks or any resources; to be fair, this merely describes the end-result, not the path that the code took to get there, so I can't say technically if `DEALLOCATE` actually *calls* `CLOSE` or merely duplicates some functionality handled by `CLOSE`, nor am I sure if that distinction even matters to anyone outside of someone who would be maintaining that code).

I did some testing and found that both `DEALLOCATE` by itself and `CLOSE` have the same effect: the "CURSOR"-based locks on the table are removed. I found no evidence of `DEALLOCATE` by itself leaving any locks in place. I tested with a sensitive / scrollable cursor with `SCROLL_LOCKS` enabled in a transaction while doing an `UPDATE ... WHERE CURRENT OF Cursor`. Each `FETCH` took an `IU` lock on the page, a `U` lock on the key, & an `IX` lock on the table, all with a lock owner type of `CURSOR`. The `UPDATE` itself duplicated those 3 locks with `TRANSACTION` as the owner type (well, minor differences in the Page and Key lock-types). After either `DEALLOCATE` or `CLOSE`, only the transaction locks remained.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer! Very well explained.

Comment: @feO2x No problem. Just FYI, I haven't yet verified Jeroen's statement in a comment on the question: "_ if a cursor is fully deallocated but not closed, the locks the cursor held (if any) remain in place until the end of the transaction_". I'll try to prove / disprove that. If it's true, then my statement of `DEALLOCATE` closes the cursor would likely be incorrect. I will let you know what I find. Outside of that potential locking issue, my conjecture was that a non-existent cursor cannot be open, hence it's closed, but that doesn't _necessarily_ mean it went though a "CLOSE" process, I guess.

Comment: @feO2x I found that both `DEALLOCATE` by itself and `CLOSE` have the same effect: the "CURSOR"-based locks on the table are removed. I found no evidence of `DEALLOCATE` by itself leaving any locks in place. I tested with a sensitive / scrollable cursor in a transaction while doing an `UPDATE ... WHERE CURRENT OF Cursor`. Each `FETCH` took an `IU` lock on the page, a `U` lock on the key, & an `IX` lock on the table, all with a lock owner type of `CURSOR`. The `UPDATE` itself duplicated those 3 locks with `TRANSACTION` as the owner type. After `DEALLOCATE` or `CLOSE` only tran locks existed.

Comment: Solomon, thank you so much for your efforts. I think the infos in your last two comments should be put into your answer. I also created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2987) so that this could end up in the Microsoft official docs.

Comment: @feO2x You're quite welcome. I had updated slightly earlier but just updated again to add the notes regarding the locking-tests. I didn't add a link to your GitHub issue since I already had that in the answer :-). P.S. I also added an answer to this [S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57999805/577765) that was mentioned in comments on the question.